# Optimize a long running SELECT DISTINCT query and where to use 'EXPLAIN' in the Query?

Tags: php, mysql

Where exactly do i use EXPLAIN in the below code and can anyone suggest on how to speed up/optimize this code (for 4 Million rows in jobseeker table an jos_users table)

```
$query =  " SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.name,dl.id id_deg,dl.degree_level,
               (SELECT r.hits FROM #__jbjobs_resume_view r WHERE r.jseeker_id=a.user_id AND r.employer_id=$user->id) AS hits, 
               (SELECT featured FROM #__jbjobs_resume WHERE is_active='y' AND featured=1 AND featured_expire > NOW() AND jseeker_id=a.user_id) as featuredres FROM #__jbjobs_jobseeker a".
              " LEFT JOIN #__users b ON a.user_id=b.id ".
              " LEFT JOIN #__jbjobs_degree_level dl ON a.id_degree_level = dl.id".
              " LEFT JOIN #__jbjobs_custom_field_value c ON c.userid=a.user_id".
              " WHERE ".$where."AND b.block='0'".
              " ORDER BY featuredres DESC";
```

[image: Structure 1] [image: struc2][image: struct3]

Comment: `$query =  "EXPLAIN SELECT...`

Comment: those sub-queries will hit your performance a lot

Comment: @wiseguy I tried it but it does not work...there is no error though!!

Comment: @firestream i know...it has acually hit the performance...i actually am looking for a solution on to increase the performance.

Answer (score 2):

resume_view.hits and resume.featured will only ever return 0 or 1 row? If so, you should be able to do it all through LEFT JOINs. If there are zero rows, then the value will be NULL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.name,dl.id id_deg,dl.degree_level, 
      r.hits,  
      r2.featured AS featuredres
 FROM #__jbjobs_jobseeker a 
    LEFT JOIN #__users b ON a.user_id=b.id  
    LEFT JOIN #__jbjobs_degree_level dl ON a.id_degree_level = dl.id 
    LEFT JOIN #__jbjobs_custom_field_value c ON c.userid=a.user_id 

    LEFT JOIN #__jbjobs_resume_view r ON r.jseeker_id=a.user_id AND r.employer_id = $user_id
    LEFT JOIN #__jbjobs_resume r2 ON r2.is_active='y' AND r2.featured=1 AND r2.featured_expire > NOW() AND r2.jseeker_id=a.user_id

    WHERE $where AND b.block='0' 
    ORDER BY featuredres DESC
```

Comment: Doesn't give ant results? At all? Can you paste the table structure in your question, then, please

Comment: Using text - it's a little bit of effort. Use a code block (indent with 4 spaces in the editor) and space out column name, type and mark any relationships. Only need the relational fields or the "select by" fields. There is also a fiddle for SQL (sqlfiddle.com) that may make it easier - put in there and add the link to your question instead.

Comment: i have inserted images..perhaps you can right click and download...i am planning to to remove it later..

Comment: Sorry - that's just the users table. We'd need structure of #__jbjobs_jobseeker,  #__jbjobs_resume_view, #__jbjobs_resume (but onyl fields used in a relationship and the "WHERE". Text is a lot easier - each time you edit it gets moved to the top of the pile, and someone else may see the structure and be able to help as well - so make it easy for them to read.